Why is my RK4 simulation of a charged particle in an uniform magnetic field is giving me a spiral orbit instead of a circular one?
I'm doing a simulation in C of charged particle in an uniform magnetic field, using RK4 integration. I'm graphing the x-y trajectory and I know it should be a circular orbit, but instead I'm getting a spiral. I don't know where the error in my implementation is.
Here is my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void ki(double t, double *observables, double *f, double *B, double *E);
void RK4(double t, double *observables, double *f, double dt, double *B, double *E);
void cross_product(double *observables, double *B);
double dot_product(double *observables, double *E);

#define m_e 0.511 // MeV
double cross[3];
double dt = 0.01;
double T = 10;
double x_0 = 0;
double vx_0 = 1;
double y_0 = 0;
double vy_0 = 0;
double z_0 = 0;
double vz_0 = 0;

int main(void){

    double E[3] = {0, 0, 0};
    double B[3] = {0,0,5};

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("EMfield.dat", "w");


    double observables[6]; // Vector que guarda las posiciones y velocidades
    double f[6]; // Vector que guarda los diferenciales, con lo cual se calcula RK

    observables[0] = x_0;
    observables[1] = vx_0; // velocidad en x
    observables[2] = y_0;
    observables[3] = vy_0; // velocidad en y
    observables[4] = z_0;
    observables[5] = vz_0; // velocidad en z

    for(double t=0;t<T;t+=dt){
        RK4(t,observables,f,dt, B, E);
        double kinetic = 0.5*m_e*(pow(observables[1],2) + pow(observables[3],2) + pow(observables[5],2));
        double potential = dot_product(observables, E);
        double ENE_TOT = kinetic + potential;
        fprintf(fp,"%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\n",t,observables[0], observables[2], observables[4], ENE_TOT);
        }
    fclose(fp);

}

void ki(double t, double *observables, double *f, double *B, double *E){

    double a[3];
    cross_product(observables, B);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) a[i] = -(E[i] + cross[i])/m_e;

    f[0] = observables[1] + a[0]*t/2;
    f[1] = a[0];
    f[2] = observables[3] + a[1]*t/2;
    f[3] = a[1];
    f[4] = observables[5] + a[2]*t/2;
    f[5] = a[2];

}

void RK4(double t, double *observables, double *f, double dt, double *B, double *E){
    double coef_k[4] = {0., 0.5, 0.5, 1.};
    double coef[4] = {1./6, 1./3, 1./3, 1./6};

    double f_act[6];
    double acum[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        double ta = t + coef_k[i]*dt;
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) f_act[j] = observables[j] + coef_k[i]*dt*f[j];
        ki(ta, f_act, f, B, E);
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) acum[j] += coef[i]*dt*f[j];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++) observables[i] += acum[i];
}

void cross_product(double *observables, double *B){
    cross[0] = observables[3]*B[2] - observables[5]*B[1];
    cross[1] = -observables[1]*B[2] + observables[5]*B[0];
    cross[2] = observables[1]*B[1] - observables[3]*B[0];
}

double dot_product(double *observables, double *E){
    return observables[0]*E[0] + observables[2]*E[1] + observables[4]*E[2];
}


This is the spiral orbit
I've tried changing the total time and different values of B, T and initial conditions and I always get the same results.

It looks like something close to 3 is missing somewhere. It could be a missing π

Have you tried decreasing the granularity (dt) to see what happens? I have a feeling numerical integration of periodic functions the way you're doing it is always unstable.

Why is the derivative of the position not just the velocity, but has a second term f[0] = observables[1] + a[0]*t/2; that is dx/dt = vx + t/2*ax?
